# How to make the last letter of a word become capitalized

Tags: java

So I'm new to coding and my teacher asked us to make a code that does this. I need to use substring to do it.

This is what I have to do.

Example output 1:
Welcome to the twist around (made up language) translation program.

Enter word to translate: Helicopter
Word in twistaround: OpterhelicCR

Example output 2:
Welcome to the twist around (made-up language) translation program.

Enter word to translate: Hello
Word in twist around: LohelLO

Notes:
Translated words are formed like this: 
Helicopter = OpterhelicCR
First letter of the second half in uppercase: Opter
First letter of the first half in lower case: helic
Last letter of the first half in uppercase: C
Last letter of the second half in uppercase: R

This is my code.
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

```
    System.out.println("Welcome to the twistAround (made up language) translation program.\n");

    System.out.print("Enter word to translate: ");
    String word = input.nextLine();

    String secondHalf = word.substring(word.length() / 2, word.length());

    System.out.println(secondHalf);
```

Output: 
Welcome to the twistAround (made up language) translation program.

Enter word to translate: Helicopter
opter
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4 seconds)

So far, I've got it to output opter. However, I'm not sure how I would capitalize the "o".

Comment: If I've done something wrong with the way I post, please tell me so I don't make the same mistake. 

Thank you.

Comment: Check out what the java [documentation on strings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) can do for you on, I'd bet you find something useful regarding upper/lowercase. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

1 - one way to use charAt method and get the first character.

2 - change the case of character and add it to string.

```
    String secondHalf = "opter";
    char a = secondHalf.charAt(0);
    secondHalf = secondHalf.substring(1);
    secondHalf = Character.toString(a).toUpperCase()+secondHalf;
    System.out.println(secondHalf);
```

3 - one other way to use substring method and then remove first character. changer the case. then add it to string.

```
    String secondHalf = "opter";
    String a = secondHalf.substring(0, 1);
    secondHalf = secondHalf.substring(1);
    secondHalf = a.toUpperCase()+secondHalf;
    System.out.println(secondHalf);
```

Comment: Technicall all that may be right, but it also might prevent that @lazy-papyrus discovers the java documentation :-/

Answer (score 0):

*the use of a* `StringBuilder` *prevents the unnecessary generation of  strings*

```
String secondHalf = "opter";
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder( secondHalf );
buf.setCharAt( 0, Character.toUpperCase( buf.charAt( 0 ) ) );
buf.toString();  // "Opter"
```

`secondHalf` may not be empty
otherwise a `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown